# How to map a deeply nested object in Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

i'm getting started with rxjs in angular2.  many of the examples i've seen use simple objects when mapping an http response to an observable.

```
 this.http.get('/app/shared/data/raw-tasks.json')
        .map(response => response.json())
        .map(stream => stream.map(res => new TaskModel(res.name, res.deadline, res.timeRequired)))
```

but how do i map a more complicated response like nested objects and nested arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you get the json from the response you can do with it whatever you want. Just add another map function and parse it somewhere else (make sure you return parsed value):

```
 this.http.get('/app/shared/data/raw-tasks.json')
   .map(response => response.json())
   .map(stream => complicatedParser(stream))

 // somewhere in your code...
 complicatedPatser(stream) {
    return stream
      .map(x => x)
      .filter(x => true)
      .reduce(....)
 }
```

Observables don't care what they emit, so there's little difference between simple string or complicated nested objects. If you know how to handle basic types, `object` and/or `array` response, you know pretty much everything (;